# Does cooking change the calorie content of food?

Tags: nutrient-composition, calories

If I look up the nutritional information of my raw ingredients to a recipe, will the calorie content of the cooked combination simply be the sum or do chemical reactions during cooking change this value significantly?

For example, if I look up the calorie content of raw tomatoes, onions and garlic, will my pasta sauce simply contain the sum of these used after being simmered for several hours?

It's clear that high temperature frying can burn the food which would obviously burn some calories quite literally, but what about boiling, simmering or baking?

A follow-up question would be what about macronutrients such as protein, carbs and fat content?

There is plenty of evidence already that cooking reduces vitamin content so the question of micronutrients does not need to be discussed.

Comment: Check out the second answer in https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/66/7180, it has the answer to your question (summary: It's Complicated).

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/calories-pre-cooked-vs-cooked