# How can I calculate the nutritional value of something homemade?

Tags: nutrient-composition

Does the baking/cooking process change the nutritional value of food? I don't know the science behind that.

I want to calculate more than just calories -fat, carbs, sugars, protein, etc... Is it just as simple (albeit, time consuming) as adding up those values on the ingredients? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: It's all just an estimate anyways. I can't imagine baking changes enough to matter provided you don't burn off a significant amount of the bread.

Comment: Yep - only thing that should be lost in baking is water, and water is 0 anything and 0% anything :)

Comment: Questions on nutrition are off topic on this site.

Comment: @GdD actually the tag "nutrient-composition" exists because the nutritional value is an exception of the "no nutrition" rule.

Comment: Edited for clarity. The question flagged as duplicate refers specifically to calories only.

Comment: Hello @TheSmallestOne Thank you for editing, it seems indeed that I picked a wrong duplicate target. We also have http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/ and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24147, and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40286, so in its current form, it would be a duplicate of one of those. Is there something different you needed? If yes, please edit it so we can also see the difference to them.