# Reliability of nutritional information readily available on the internet

Tags: potatoes, fiber

I've seen [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/87412/do-potatoes-and-rice-lose-significant-amount-of-fiber-when-overcooked) but I find statistics online which seem to say otherwise. [This site](https://www.verywellfit.com/french-fries-nutrition-facts-and-health-benefits-5070457) says there are 1.6g of fiber in 100g french fries but apparently if I were to boil 100g of potatoes instead then I'd have 1.8g of fiber according to [this site](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/foods/potatoes#nutrition).

What gives? Wrong information? If so, what are the correct fiber qunatites.

Comment: 1.6 and 1.8 are very similar numbers, and all nutritional information for natural products is a rough estimate because they aren't consistent. If anything I'm surprised that two websites have numbers so close together.

Comment: @dbmag9 that's an answer

Comment: I’d actually expect there to be more fiber in fried potatoes (because moisture is lost when frying, leaving you with less weight, so more raw potato is required for 100g fried vs 100g boiled)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.6 and 1.8 are very similar numbers, and **all nutritional information for natural products is a rough estimate because they aren't consistent**. If anything I'm surprised that two websites have numbers so close together.

*I don't think there are exact duplicates, but this certainly isn't the first question here along the lines of 'why do different sources give different amounts for the nutrients in a natural product?' and I will try to find some of the others to edit them in later, as they have more detailed answers.*

Comment: I wrote [one on peanuts](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/66606/20413) , and I've also written something on moisture loss but that may have been comments on someone else's answer