# Calculating the effect of a marinade on nutrition

Tags: marinade, nutrient-composition

While watching a collection of [olive oil based chicken marinade recipes](http://www.myrecipes.com/well-done/how-to-make-4-chicken-marinades) *I was wondering if there is an effective way of calculating the effect that a marinade might have on the nutritional value of meat being marinaded?* While I am principally interested in 'calories' I would also like to, for instance, be able to calculate differences in fats and/or carbs. I am not so interested (at the moment) about vitamins or minerals.

The tools I have seen simply aggregate the total of ingredients, but in a marinade many of those ingredients are left behind (and therefore should not count as calories for the dish) but I have to believe (and other articles suggest as much) that there is 'an effect' but I am yet to find a manner for calculating that effect.

Several answers to [How to calculate the calorie content of cooked food?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/66/6279) dance around the question, and as @Bikerboy389 suggests, maybe I'm "*sweating the small stuff*" here...still I would like to know. Especially where oils are concerned I'm thinking the effect might be more than just 'a little'

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "nutritional value". If you're just interested in the calories, say that.

Comment: Yes, I edited that in.

Comment: That's helpful. I think we may have some similar questions that would address this. I'm guessing the answer is something along the lines of "it is a negligible amount of change". Most of the questions about absorption rates of marinades seem to imply that there's very little absorption, so I'd bet that your unlikely to need to worry about this... but I'd be happy to have it proved otherwise.

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks, I would agree that this is a duplicate, surprised it didn't come up when I labeled the question (or on a google search before I tried..). I fully expect that this would be a difficult question to answer (at best) but I have been surprised before. Since an answer more conclusive than the one provided is unlikely to be forthcoming I will delete this one shortly. (will wait a few minutes so you have the chance to see my reply.)

Comment: You don't have to delete duplicate questions - actually, the preference are to let them stay, for exactly the problem into which you ran. Two people can express the same problem in different words, and then the search engine fails to help them. The more differently worded duplicates hang around - but closed and pointing to a single place with answers as opposed to having half-duplicated answers spread among them - the more likely that the next person searching will find it.